# Returning an error istead of value under a certain condition

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript, graphql

So I have a schema for user, and offers. In short, you need to pass a usedId to create an offer. And it has to be valid (user with this id needs to exist in the db). I figured out that much. But now I'm not sure how to correctly return error message/null in a resolver. Here's the code:

resolver:

```
createOffer: async (
  parent: parentType, {
    authorId,
  },
) => {
  const author = await UserModel.findById(authorId);
  if (!author) {
    console.log("Author doesn't exist");
    // todo Add error message return
    return null;
  }
  return OfferModel.create(
    {
      authorId,
    },
  ).catch(handlePromiseError);
},
```

mutation:

```
export const OfferMutations = gql`
    extend type Mutation {
        createOffer(
            authorId: String,
        ): Offer!, # I want to return here Offer, or error type/null.
                   # I was thinking I could do || or | the ts way, but no luck.
    }
`;
```

How can I fix that? Or is my architecture/thinking about this wrong?

Comment: You can `throw` an error and then put whatever message or other properties you want in the Error object you throw.  Since this would be in an `async` function, it would end up rejecting the returned promise with that Error object as the reject reason.  The caller would need to pay attention to promise rejections.

Comment: @jfriend00 That's a good idea. Would you like to make it an answer so I can select as best?

Comment: Answer written with the `throw` suggestion in it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can `throw` an error and then put whatever message or other properties you want in the `Error` object you throw.  This is a classic use of throwing an error when you need to distinguish an error return from normally returned data and you may want to include a reason for the error in the return value.

Since this is in an `async` function, it would end up rejecting the returned promise with that `Error` object as the reject reason. The caller would need to pay attention to promise rejections.

Answer (score 1):

I think this function worth splitting into two - easier to read and test.
First function will check if user exists, second function will operate on user.

You can also consider some default object for `User`, aka `monoid`. For example:

```js
type RawUser = {
   id: string;
   name: string;
}
type DefaultUser = {
   exists: boolean
}

type User = RawUser & DefaultUser;
```

Personaly, I'm trying to make sure that function always return only one type.

Honestly, the best option in such cases is to use functional programming paradigm. You can use smth like `Option<T>` type which is in `fp-ts` library.